# VB script unable to access file

Tags: excel, time, vbscript, vba

I am trying to schedule a vba script.  I am working through the company server and am wondering if I can not access this due to administrative restrictions? here is the code:

```
 Dim xlApp
 Dim xlBook

 Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\\Computer\denfs1\data\1EpUSRgltry\Permitting - Wells &    Sundries\WEST (CO-MT-ND)\Schedules & Status\Planning and Permiting Spread sheet(West) Permit and    Planning spread sheet.xlsm", 0, True)
 xlApp.Run "Click"
 xlBook.Close
 xlApp.Quit

 Set xlBook = Nothing
 Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Here is the error I am getting[image]

Answer (score 1):

What does the macro "Click" do? If it make changes, close it without saving (change to True if you want to save changes by the Click macro).

```
xlBook.Close False
```

You may also want to debug from Excel by putting `xlApp.Visible = True` before opening the .xlsm workbook.

There might be a hidden Excel.exe locking that same file from previous script execution (say you press Ctrl-C before the macro "Click" finishes). Close all visible Excel windows and ensure there are no Excel.exe running in task manager.

If you keep pressing Cancel when Excel asks you to save changes to it, it will stuck in background even the vbs did not pick up any error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a syntax error with the name of the file... Make sure you have the whole string accurate :/